# redux thunk wait data from a dispatch before to do an another dispatch

Tags: reactjs, api, redux, twitch, thunk

I'm trying to improve my code by trying to use redux thunk as well as possible but I've searched a lot, no solution corresponds to my research.

Basically, with the twitch API we have to make 2 API calls, one to get the authentication key and another to get the data from this key.

Here is my current code:

```
        dispatch(getOauthKey())      
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {

        if(refresh){
            dispatch(getAllStreams(oAuthKey.access_token))
        }
        
    }, [oAuthKey.access_token])
```

Here I had to use a true/false with refresh to know when to dispatch or not and [oAuthkey.access_token] to restart the useEffect when the variable receives data.

It works but it's not optimized at all and I know you can chain dispatches with thunk but I couldn't do it. Here is what I tried to do:

```
    const thunkA = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch(getOauthKey())
        
    }

    const thunkB = (key) =>(dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch(getAllStreams(key))
       
    }
    console.log(oAuthKey.access_token)
    useEffect(()=> {
        dispatch(thunkA()).then(() =>dispatch(thunkB(oAuthKey.access_token))
      );
        
    }, [])
```

And I have this as an error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then'). I specify that the first call api sends the key into the store so the oAuthKey comes from the latter

Sorry I'm really new to reactjs / redux / thunk and the problem doesn't jump out at me here haha.

thank a lot in advance

Comment: is the problem has beed solved?

Answer (score 0):

There are several options to do that. as a standard `redux-thunk` solution, you can use promise changing for dispatching the actions in the `thunk`.

First of all, you need to add this package: `redux-promise-middleware` with the official [documentation](https://github.com/pburtchaell/redux-promise-middleware/blob/main/docs/introduction.md#installation).

> Given a single action with an async payload, the middleware transforms the action to separate pending action and a separate fulfilled/rejected action, representing the states of the async action.

Now you can chain your actions:

```
const chainMyActions = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    const response = dispatch(thunkA());

    response.then((data) => {
      dispatch(thunkB(data.access_token))
    })
  }
}
```

Now you can call the sample `chainMyActions` function in your `useEffect`.

Comment: I tried a few things with the method you gave me and it seems that it does not wait for the api to send the answer before executing the rest.

I could see with several console.log that I get the key from the twitch api long after the thunk A and B chain are finished. so thunkA returns an undefined and blocks everything else

Comment: did you installed the `redux-promise-middleware` library? did you config it properly ? I mean add this middleware to the list of your middleware ? @Misen

Comment: yup I added const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk, promise)(createStore) inside my store.js and I have this error : Error: Expected the root reducer to be a function. Instead, received: 'undefined'.  If I'm removing the (creatstore) at the end, the app run but still the undifned problem

Comment: your appluMiddleware input shouldn't be an array? @Misen

Comment: not to my knowledge

Comment: I think the problem is here @Misen